# CLT-based confidence interval vs. Bootstrap based confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm learning Hypothesis testing and defining confidence intervals on samples.

And trying to note down the advantages and disadvantages of reporting a CLT-based 95% confidence interval for a difference of proportions, compared with reporting a bootstrap-based 95% confidence interval a difference of proportions.

For now what Ive come up with is the CLT based approximation requiring a large sample size, and an assumption that the sample is normally distributed while the bootstrap approach doesn't require much but requires some variability in data.

Any additions to this is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in two proportions is such a simple thing that you would think that statisticians had solved the confidence interval problem long ago.  Instead we have another reason to use Bayesian inference, as it provides exact uncertainty (credibility) intervals for this difference, where we do not have a unique exact confidence interval.  There are many confidence intervals for the difference in two probabilities you can find in the literature.  That being said, binary data are well behaved because of being tied down to [0,1], and aymptotic CLT-like intervals are fairly accurate.  You may want to run a little simulation for your situation and sample size to check this.  Be sure to compute both the left and right non-coverage probabilities, not just the overall coverage probability when doing simulations.  I doubt that the bootstrap is worth the trouble here, and the bootstrap is only approximate, unless you use the more computationally expensive double bootstrap to get confidence intervals to a high order of correctness.